# How can I cut what I want out of a huge data dump?

Tags: sql, file, text

I've got a 3.55 GB .txt file, which is too big to get into Access. It's got about 5 million records in it and I only a small portion of those. I need a way to parse out the lines of data that I need and get rid of the bulk of the data. Each line of text is 651 characters, but fortunately we can sort it by the first three. If I can delete any line that doesn't begin with  044, 067, 122, or 107, I'll have the file down to a size that I'll be able to load into Access. I've loaded both cygwin and mysql onto the machine, now I'm staring at the command prompts wondering what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got cygwin, then something like

```
grep '^(044|067|122|107)' file.csv > newfile.csv
```

would do the trick. Might need to enable grep's regex options, but my brain's in Friday Mush mode right now and can't remember what they are offhand.

Comment: If I read the OP right, you *wouldn't* want -v. "...delete any line that *doesn't* begin with 044, 067, 122, or 107..." = keep any line that does begin with 044, 067, 122, or 107

Comment: I'm attempting grep '^\(044\|067\|122\|107\) input txt > output.txt.     It's doing something. We'll soon see.

Comment: Oops! left out a '  When I replaced it, it says no such file or directory.

Comment: I got it. Windows was hiding the .txt, so when I renamed the file, it was actually input.txt.txt. All better now. Thanks.